# SQL Server create correct relationship between tables

Tags: sql-server

Well it's a noob question but I really appricate your answers.

I want to create a `tournament` table with start and end date columns. Each tournament contains 32th finale, 16th finale, semi final and final.

I can't figure out what would be the most correct way to design such a database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can identify 2 entities: `Tournament` and `Round`. A Tournament can have many Rounds.

The Tournament table could contain the Start and End dates as columns:

```
Id: Primary Key
Start: Date 
End: Date
```

A Round table could contain the tournament id and round type (of course you could decide to add participants, score and any other relevant information to the round):

```
Id: Primary Key
TournamentId: Foreign Key pointing to the corresponding tournament
Type: Integer (that would identify the type of round 32, 16, 8, ..)
```

Comment: Yeah i was thinking such way,  i was correct , thank for your answer